# Simple angular ng-repeat app not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ajax

Pretty sure this is something stupid and I know it's pretty much a dupe question. 
I have a VERY simple angular app and some HTML.

When debugging on chrome I can see that I am getting a response from my ajax call and that it's definitely populating my $scope.courses. Yet for some reason it does not want to work. Tried looking for spelling issues to no success.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="registrationApp" ng-controller="registrationController"  >
    <div class="spacer" ng-repeat="course in courses">
    <label>{{course.Name}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    var app = angular.module("registrationApp", []);
    app.controller("registrationController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "";
    $scope.lastName = "";
    $scope.cellNumber = "";
    $scope.emailAddress = "";
    $scope.selectCourse = "";
    $scope.courseCategories = [];
    $scope.courses = [];

    $scope.loadCourses = function () {
        var jqxhr = $.ajax("http://localhost/APIWrapper/api/course")
        jqxhr.done(function (response) {
            $scope.courses = response;
        })
        jqxhr.fail(function () {
            alert("error");
        })
        jqxhr.always(function () {

        });
    }

    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        $scope.loadCourses();
    });

});
```

Response:

[image: Response Image]

Comment: Could we see a bit more? Where is course.Name being defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular doesn't know anything about what's going on in your ajax service, so it does not know to update the UI. Try using $http or $resource instead. [See the Angular tutorial for details](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07).

---

Edit

Just to clarify relative to [Michał Urbańczyk's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4443332/micha%c5%82-urba%c5%84czyk) answer, $http operates within the angular digest loop, so the UI will automatically be updated when the service returns. If you go outside of Angular, you have to notify Angular explicitly, as Michal did.

But you can run into unexpected problems going outside Angular, so unless there's a compelling reason to do that, you probably should not.

Comment: I injected the $http into my app. Not sure what that does really. Then I replaced my current call ' $.ajax' with ' $.http(' . Please can you explain the concept to me on a high level and maybe some additional documentation to link?

Comment: Did you notice the tutorial link in my answer?

Comment: I have thank you. I'm more curious to the difference between the $http and $resource or $.ajax or one the others I have stumbled upon. It feels like I'm missing something really fundamental here.

Comment: I've always assumed it was just different syntax or something. What I really don't understand as well is why the $scope.courses did in fact receive data. After stepping through the code as per screen shot you can clearly see it populated.

Comment: I think $resource is supposed to be more high-level and easier to use, but to be honest I usually just use $http. $.ajax is just using raw jQuery outside angular.

Comment: Yes, it populates, but angular has to run logic that updates what's on the screen in the databindings once that happens, and it has no way to know it needs to run that logic when you go outside the system.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance Amy. Will try to read up on some documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried enclosing `$scope.courses = response;` in:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
   $scope.courses = response;
})
```

Angular needs to know when to run scope digest.

Comment: It's better to just communicate with the service "the angular way."

Comment: Sure, way better and way simpler. I'm just posting fix for the problem.

Comment: I agree with Amy here. I have had to use that solution before. This however is way to simple and should work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Better way to use $http or $resource in angular. $http internally invoke ajax call to fetch data, when we call $http.get(url) method than the $http service automatically adds certain HTTP headers like for example X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest.

html

```
<body ng-app="registrationApp">
  <div ng-controller="registrationController">
    <ul ng-repeat="course in courses">
      <li>{{course.Name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

js - Controller

```
var app = angular.module("registrationApp", []);

app.controller("registrationController", function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://localhost/APIWrapper/api/course').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.courses = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      // log error
    });
});
```

> In your data must have a Name field.